# Access static method of generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, static

I currently have something like this:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    public abstract string title();
}

class Derived1 : BaseClass {
    public override string title() { return "D1"; }
}

class Derived2 : BaseClass {
    public override string title() { return "D2"; }
}

class Receiver<T> where T : BaseClass {
    private T obj;
    public string objTitle() { return obj.title(); }
}
```

The problem I am running into is that, if `obj` is `null`, `objTitle` throws a null reference exception. I can guarentee in this case that `title` will always return the same string for a given derived type; is there any way to make `Receiver` able to access it on the generic parameter `T`? My instinct is to use a `static`, but I don't know of any way to make a static visible to the `Reciever`; there's no way to make a base class or constraint specifying it.

Comment: Which class are Derived1 and Derived2 derived from? Base? Why not decide that class Receiver must receive obj in the constructor?

Comment: It does receive `obj` in the constructor, but there's no guarantee that it will be non-null.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection to call a static method on the type, or if the value is actually a constant, you could also instantiate a new instance if there isn't an instance yet.

```
class Receiver<T> where T : BaseClass, new() {
    private T obj;
    public string objTitle() { return (obj ?? new T()).title(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is construct the T immediately and drop the if

```
class Receiver<T> where T : BaseClass, new() {
    private T obj = new T();
    public string objTitle() { return obj.title(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can't override static methods. From your design I can see that "title" is independent with an instance of BaseClass/Derived1/Derived2. Adding an instance method `title()` doesn't make sense here. I recommend you design these classes like this: (I renamed the classes to make it easy to understand)

```
abstract class MessageBase { }
class TextMessage : MessageBase { }
class ImageMessage : MessageBase { }

class Receiver<T> where T : MessageBase
{
    public string GetMessageTitle()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(TextMessage)) return "Text";
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ImageMessage)) return "Image";
        return "Default";
    }
}
```